# Deploy packaged shiny app on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

When having a shiny app set up like this for the shiny server

```
+---/srv/shiny-server
|   +---shinyApp1
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
```

all works fine. However, how can I do the same, when the above files (`ui.R`, `server.R`) are included in a packages `inst/shiny` folder? (see, for example, my [gridsampler](https://github.com/markheckmann/gridsampler) repo).

**How can I deploy a packaged shiny app on shiny server?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what I do.

I host a lot of shiny apps from packages on [my shiny server](https://daattali.com/shiny) and what I do is just `setwd()` to the directory of the shiny app and then call `shinyAppDir(".")`.

As an example: [this code](https://github.com/daattali/shiny-server/blob/master/colourInput/app.R) is responsible for [this app](https://daattali.com/shiny/colourInput/)

---

Edit 2.5 years later: note that this will not work if you have a global.R file - see this issue on github https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1063

My workaround for that is to explicitly source global.R

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: I agree, I'll probably use this method from here on out, too.

Comment: Tried it, but I get an error about the app not finding variables defines in `global.R` – Can't seem to figure out why. The symlink-method I suggested works, though.

Comment: Did some digging, `global.R` doesn't work intentionally in this configuration, but there are workarounds (like explicitly source'ing it), and now it works. Discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/shiny-discuss/ibAXs3zLWAs/YOVRVRU2AQAJ

Comment: Yes that's true.  I do find that annoying.  I opened a bug about that in RStudio's github issues a long time ago, feel free to add your opinion there to show them that other people also think it's annoying :)  My workaround is to explicitly source global.R

Answer (score 2):

I went for the easy way and just cloned the package from GitHub into the shiny-server directory and have to manually link to the `inst/shiny` subdirectory, see [my hosted version of gridsampler](https://gauss.tadaa-data.de/projects/gridsampler/inst/shiny/) as an example (notice the non-pretty URL). The shiny-server is set up to host a directory of apps, hence the overview when [visiting the root URL](https://gauss.tadaa-data.de) where you need to click through to the app.

Other possibilities might include cloning the repository somewhere outside the shiny-server folder and symlinking the `inst/shiny` folder into the shiny-server folder as `gridsampler`, which afaik should work if appropriate permissions are set.

Comment: how do you link to the `inst/shiny` subdirectory? In the server config or what do mean by linking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MarkHeckmann Linking as in "copy the URL to that subdirectory", i.e. `https://gauss.tadaa-data.de/projects/gridsampler/inst/shiny/` – This may require the shiny-server to be set up to host a directory of app, see http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#host-a-directory-of-applications for config info. My shiny server is set up like that and the server root looks like this: https://paste.xinu.at/2Lojkf/

Comment: I think an even easier way is to just run the app from the installed directory using `shinyAppDir()`

Comment: @DeanAttali, Is it possible to install "https://github.com/JinmiaoChenLab/cytofkit2/blob/master/R/cytofkit_shinyAPP.R" in the R Shiny server running on ubuntu? If so, can you kindly advise how?